# Chef Server on different port

Tags: chef-infra

I installed a **chef server 11** on a Server that is behind a firewall, ie I had to set up some natting for this server to be available and as a result the server is reachable on port 449 from the outside (instead of default 443 https port).
Now I installed chef on my workstation, and set up knife. I set my chef_server_url as https://blahblah.com:449 (thats a bogus domain) . Now I can connect with knife to the server, since if I run something like 'knife client list', it does give the list. However, if I want to upload a cookbook, it does not do it, an it looks as if it tries to connect to the chef_server_url on the normal port 443:

```
h046n100:chef-repo chris$ knife cookbook upload hostname
Uploading hostname       [0.1.0]
ERROR: Network Error: Error connecting to https://blahblah.com/sandboxes/00000000000020ec9bdebdbdaff8b9ed - Operation timed out - connect(2)
Check your knife configuration and network settings
```

Any ideas anyone why it is doing this, and if/how it is possible to tell chef to use port 449?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You have to create or edit `/etc/chef-server/chef-server.rb` and add the line below:

```
nginx['ssl_port'] = 449
```

Then run:

```
sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure
sudo chef-server-ctl restart
```

Please see [the docs](http://docs.opscode.com/config_rb_chef_server.html).

Comment: As an FYI for chef-server 12, the config file is now /etc/opscode/chef-server.rb . I searched for it during about 30 minutes, but found your answer in the firsts minutes. So I though I should leave that here :)  Cheers

Comment: If you try this you should be aware of this bug: https://github.com/chef/chef-server/issues/50

Answer (score 0):

could you try running below command:

```
knife cookbook upload hostname --server-url https://blahblah.com:449
```

If this works, then you need to update your knife.rb with below line:

```
chef_server_url "https://blahblah.com:449"
```